# Jquery/Javascript - Capture the position of the page screen or an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I need to get a position of a DIV relative to the body or html tag.

So for example:

- I have a  element going up the screen.
- When you scroll the page vertically, and the DIV is at certain height on the screen, it changes color.
- When the DIV is off the screen, it changes back to its normal color.

I have done something similar to this, but I have to use Next/Previous buttons for it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>

    var number = 0;
    var goSign = "";

    function goToByScroll(id){              
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top-100},'slow','swing', function()
            {
                $('#'+id).css('background', '#8b00cb');
                $('#'+(id-1)).css('background', 'none');
                $('#'+(id+1)).css('background', 'none');    
            });             


    }

    function iterate(goSign)
    {                               
        if(goSign == "next")
        {           

            if(number < 12 && number >= 0)
            {
                goToByScroll(++number);
            }
            //alert(number);
        }
        else if(goSign == "previous")
        {
            if(number <= 12 && number >= 1)
            {
                goToByScroll(--number);
            }               
            //alert(number);
        }
    }

    </script>


</head>
<body>

<div style = "position:fixed; top:90px;right:200px;width:200px;height:50px">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="iterate('next')">Next</a><br/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="iterate('previous')">Previous</a>
</div>


<div style="width:600px">
    <div id="1">
    <h1>1</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="2">
    <h1>2</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="3">
    <h1>3</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="4">
    <h1>4</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="5">
    <h1>1</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="6">
    <h1>2</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="7">
    <h1>3</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="8">
    <h1>4</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="9">
    <h1>1</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="10">
    <h1>2</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="11">
    <h1>3</h1>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
    <div id="12">
    <h1>4</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin orci erat, gravida vitae auctor sed, fringilla sit amet sem. Etiam scelerisque, ligula ac scelerisque egestas, sem arcu commodo ligula, in imperdiet arcu ipsum nec magna. Proin purus tellus, dictum at volutpat tempor, ultrices ut arcu. Nam ut diam vitae dui tristique tincidunt sed a est. Aenean rutrum, lectus at laoreet consectetur, erat leo vestibulum massa, eu pellentesque justo nisi a arcu. Aliquam fermentum volutpat eros, sed tempus dolor luctus eget. Sed sodales dapibus nisi ut venenatis. Phasellus suscipit risus nunc, non adipiscing purus. Morbi tristique dolor ac lacus euismod lacinia. Praesent ac nisi nec elit pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum porttitor turpis vitae velit pretium vitae tincidunt sapien varius. Nullam suscipit malesuada elit, et lacinia mauris pretium id. In sem felis, fermentum nec lobortis vel, elementum quis odio. Nullam bibendum magna quis lacus condimentum ut vestibulum nunc ultricies. In augue nisl, tincidunt vel convallis a, pretium vel diam. Sed tincidunt odio sit amet nulla cursus porta. Aenean sed quam sem, a semper mauris. Maecenas ac nulla metus. 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to do this?

I was thinking of using jQuery .position() http://api.jquery.com/position/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.position()` will give you the location of an element based on it's offset parent (so if the element is inside an absolutely positioned element you probably won't get the coordinates from the `document` element).

Try using `.offset()` instead:

> Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements, relative to the document.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/offset*

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PNCbK/ (JSFiddle seems to be having issues right now, here is a JSBin of the same code: http://jsbin.com/ezobux/edit#javascript,html,live)

Comment: hmmm..interesting. Ill keep working on my app. Thanks. I'll post results later on.